# Java: Else after multiple ifs or comparing two strings

Tags: java

Sorry if the title doesn't make sense. Basically, I'm a noob, and for learning purposes I'm trying to create a basic program which asks first for gender then for age to determine access. The program is sexist for testing purposes. Anyway, heres what I have:

```
    System.out.println("What is your Gender?");
    String gender = input.nextLine();
        if (gender.equals ("male")){
            System.out.println("What is your age?");
            int agem = input.nextInt();
            if (agem >= 21 && agem < 65){
                System.out.println("Access Granted");
            }else{
                System.out.println("Access Denied");
            }
        }
        if (gender.equals ("female")){
            System.out.println("What is your age?");
            int agef = input.nextInt();
            if (agef >=18 && agef < 60){
                System.out.println("Access Granted");
            }else{
                System.out.println("Access Denied");
            }
        }
```

Now what I am trying to do is create a response in case the user enters something other than "male" or "female". I've tried using else in the case that both if statements are false but it hasn't worked.

I also tried creating another if statement like this one:

if (!gender.equals ("male") || ("female"));

But that doesn't work either.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to restructure your program to use `if`, `else if`, `else`.

For example:

```
System.out.println("What is your Gender?");
String gender = input.nextLine();
if (gender.equals ("male")){
    System.out.println("What is your age?");
    int agem = input.nextInt();
    if (agem >= 21 && agem < 65){
        System.out.println("Access Granted");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Access Denied");
    }
} else if (gender.equals ("female")){
    System.out.println("What is your age?");
    int agef = input.nextInt();
    if (agef >=18 && agef < 60){
        System.out.println("Access Granted");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Access Denied");
    }
} else {
    System.out.println("Unrecognized input.");
}
```

This is a little more succinct, as it's not possible for it to execute the *female* branch if the *male* branch has been executed, and it's not possible for it to execute the *unrecognized* branch if either the *male* or *female* branch has been executed.

Answer (score 2):

as an immediate solution, you need to add following condition in the end

`if (!(gender.equals ("male") || gender.equals("female")));` or

`if (!gender.equals ("male") && !gender.equals("female"));`

but to avoid unnecessary condition check the whole condition should look like this:

```
        if (gender.equals ("male")){
            //
        }
        else if (gender.equals ("female")){
            //
        } else {

        }
```

and since java 7, you can also use string bases switch statement:

```
switch(value){
    case "male":
        //todo
        break;
    case "female"
        //todo
        break;
    default:
        //todo
}
```

Comment: Your first statement should be `if (!gender.equals ("male") && !gender.equals("female"))`. Otherwise, it will always evaluate to `true`

Comment: if (!(gender.equalsIgnoresCase("male") && gender.equalsIgnoresCase("female"))) will be even better to guard against input like "Male" i feel.

Answer (score 1):

this will work:

```
if (gender.equals ("male") || gender.equals("female"))
{ 
   //input is okay, do something
} 
else 
{ 
  //input is not "male" or "female"  
}
```

Comment: @wyles, Those are not equivalent.  Gender cannot both equal "male" and "female," so that would always be false.  Then you are negating it, always returning true.  Thus the block would always be executed.

Answer (score 1):

You can also go with a switch:

```
switch(gender) {
  case "male": 

    break;

  case "female":

    break;

  default: //everything else
}
```

Edit: string switch works since java 7

Answer (score 0):

The quickest solution to this would be to use:

```
if (gender.equals("Male")) {

} else if (gender.equals("Female")) {

} else {

}
```